# Validate one of two inputs with angular ng-disable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I got an form with two inputs, E-Mail and Phone-Number.
To submit the form, there is a Button, which is diabled as default.
Know my desire is, when one of the fields is correctly filld, the button get enabled.

This are my inputs:

```
<input
    type="email"
    ng-model="userEmail"
    class="form-control input-lg"
    ng-class="{error: successEmailForm.sendFeedbackMail.$invalid && successEmailForm.sendFeedbackMail.$dirty}"
    id="sendFeedbackMail"
    name="sendFeedbackMail"
    placeholder="E-Mail"
    required> // only one of two should be required


<input
    type="number"
    ng-model="userPhone"
    class="form-control input-lg"
    ng-class="{error: successEmailForm.sendFeedbackPhone.$invalid && successEmailForm.sendFeedbackPhone.$dirty}"
    id="sendFeedbackPhone"
    placeholder="TELEFON"
    id="sendFeedbackPhone"
    required
    >


<a type="button"
    class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg btn-green upper"
    id="successEmailBtn"
    ng-disabled="successEmailForm.sendFeedbackMail.$error.email || successEmailForm.sendFeedbackMail.$error.required || successEmailForm.sendFeedbackPhone.$required" 
    ng-click="postSuccess()"
    href=""
    >
```

Has anyone an Idea how this get to work?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a simple expression inside the ng-disabled directive to check the email and phone model values:

```
ng-disabled='!userEmail && !userPhone'
```